# SQL Query to search text with particular character?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I am using `postgresql 9.3`.  I am going to select a column in a table
 whose values start with particular character for example. I am having 
fruits table in which I store all fruits name in a column named `fruitname`.
Now I want to return all fruit name starts with letter `A` at the same time 
if no fruits start with letter `A` then I need to return all fruits having a letter `A`.

The main condition here is that I want to search contains letter `A` only when there is no fruits exists with
starting letter `A`.

I tried like

```
  SELECT fruitname FROM fruits WHERE fruitname LIKE 'A%' 
  union all
  SELECT fruitname FROM fruits,(SELECT count(*) as cnt FROM fruits
  WHERE fruitname LIKE 'A%') t  WHERE fruitname LIKE '%A%' and t.cnt= 0
```

It returns correct answer but I need with out sub query. Is it possible??

Answer (score 0):

How about extending the second WHERE clause ?

`SELECT fruitname FROM fruits WHERE fruitname LIKE 'A%' 
  union all
  SELECT fruitname FROM fruits 
   WHERE fruitname LIKE '%A%' AND NOT fruitname LIKE 'A%'`

Comment: thanks for reply. But i need when first condition not satisfy then only next condition work.